# Eclipse crashes with GC overhead limit exceded after linking google play services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory, libgdx

So I'm building a project using LibGdx and have had trouble for the past few days trying to fix this issue. I have followed many other posts about the same question but had no success.

Essentially as soon as I link my android project with `google-play-services-lib` and try to debug, I have my project hover at 99% completion on the debug and then receive the following error:

```
Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded                             
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

This error is received **even after** I have increased my memory in *eclipse.ini*. From what I understand you have to keep increasing until it works and I have set it up to -Xms4600m and -Xmx4600m and still experience this issue. I figured thats a bit overkill (I only have 6gb of ram) so I have lowered it for now. There has to be some sort of different solution. Below is my current *eclipse.ini* settings. Am I missing something? I have tried updating to the latest google play service as well with no success. I am stumped on what to do...

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1536M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1536m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms2028m
-Xmx4072m
```

I sincerely appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to activate `multidex`, perhaps using play services exceeds the limited number of class for Dalvik "`DEX`". look this:

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Somewhere I read this comment from a person something to fix a similar mistake, this is more or less what he said:

*I had a copy of `Google Play Services` lib inside my workspace and imported from there after delete that folder place that out of my workspace and imported again with `copy projects to my workspace` checked it worked perfectly.*

I do not know if this solved, your problem but maybe help you, if not, tell me and delete the response.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried the workspace suggestion but it hasn't worked. For reference I have made a freshly new project and freshly imported all the libraries after cleaning the workspace and it didn't work (I went into the workspace folder and deleted all projects as well). 

As for the multidex issue, I looked into it and it seems it will be telling me a completely different error if that was the case. This seems to stem from the the fact google play services is way to large for some reason. I'm going to completely delete my SDK and reinstall it. I will get back to you once that is done.

Comment: Okay thank you! I got it to work now. Essentially before deleting my sdk I decided to delete my google services off my hard drive. I deleted it from my work place and along with it I went to my SDK manager and deleted it there. I once again reinstalled it and now it works. I don't understand why it didn't work when I updated it the first time but atleast it works now. Thanks for the suggestion, I guess when you run into issues like this it is best to completely reset your files that aren't working. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad that you, you will solve, if you're right with what you comment of the error/issues, but an error sometimes little "common" generates a log that is like another very common mistake. for example the eclipse.ini, which although will be linked, and as much as looking always find the same solution, and ask yourself, I'm doing wrong. sometimes it is a matter of luck fix in an hour, or 3 days, I think I.P.S: sorry for my English